# Android Java Video Live Streaming

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, live, rtsp

I'm creating an application that can stream live video from an HTTP url. Is it possible to create a native Android app that can stream live videos directly? Or do I still need a media server to transcode video into a format supported by Android before it is sent from the server to Android via RTSP? Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a proper rtsp URL for example : `rtsp://somewhere/vod/mp4:sample.mp4`

You can open an intent by using

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(your_rtsp_address));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Sir! Thanks for your answer. Can't I just stream through HTTP protocol?

Comment: Sorry I do not know about that, I have my involvement only in Rtsp streaming.

Comment: I've already got the answer! I've done RTSP before and it needed a special media server to transcode the video into a format Android supports, so I wanted to try another method. I just used the videoView and gave it the URL of the streaming video. It should work fine if Android version 3.0 and above. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, your clarification taught me something new as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `VideoView`. by using  [VideoView.setVideoURi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) method you can show streaming.

Comment: Thanks. I've already done this yesterday. The videoView keeps telling me it can't play the video format. I'm using H264 and MP4, which are friendly to Android. I know I'm missing some configurations but I still can't figure them out.